# I will be delivering a lecture on Android development tomorrow. Any topics I should cover?

Tags: android

I have been asked by my local Association for Computing Machinery chapter to give a lecture on Android development, and while I already have some topics to cover, I was curious if the community of SO had any suggestions of things that would be interesting to hear about.

Thus selected:

- OpenGL
- Using hardware features (camera, audio, accelerometer, multitouch)
- Good UI practices
- Social media integration

Comment: how long is your lecture? who is your audience?

Comment: Two to two and a half hours, with university students that have a decent understanding of Java and XML, but not necessarily Android itself. I plan on keeping things fun and humorous, otherwise that two and a half hour lecture will end with an empty room. :)

Comment: If your audience isn't well informed about Android development then you can touch on The App Inventor from google to get them close to developing android applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your audience doesn't know Android but are interested in Android development and want to take the first steps I'd go with:

1. A bit on Android history
2. Briefly introduction to: Activities, Services, Broadcast receivers, Content providers
3. Good UI practices
4. Social media integration

You could use a simple Twitter or whatever sample client as an example to be used throughout your presentation.

--

If your presentation is aimed at making the students be interested on Android, I'd go a totally different way:

1. Brief history of Android
2. Social media integration
3. OpenGL
4. Using hardware features (camera, audio, accelerometer, multitouch)
5. Native Development

I'd go for a showcase like presentation style with snippets of code here and there to show that their knowledge of Java is still applies and the kind of cool things you can do with the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Cover android application components like

1.Activities
 2.Services
 3.Broadcast receivers
 4.Content providers

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents:

- Threading: `AsyncTask`, `Handler`/`Looper`
- Database: sqlite, `DatabaseHelper`, versioning

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you can't cover everything. You don't have enough time, so instead of trying to talk a little bit about a lot of things, spend your time on one facet that you think is most compelling.

I have found that talks that did that were often the most compelling.